# AngularJS $routeProvider Not loading content or logging to console from controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-ng-route

I am trying to make a website which does not need to refresh when going from page to page. I have achieved this before by using the angularJS [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) but for some reason my content will not load from pages other than index.html.

I've tried putting a console.log statement in my controller to see if the controller is even being reached, but the console shows nothing in the logs, so evidently the controller is not even being triggered, although the url is changing as expected (i.e. from `localhost:8000/#/` to `localhost:8000/#/LetsTalk`). Neither the home.html or LetsTalk.html content are loading, which is strange to me because I copied and pasted most of this code from a different website I made which worked perfectly.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<div class="nav mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--transparent">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <!-- Navigation -->
      <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <ul>
          <li class="four"><a href="#/LetsTalk">let's talk</a></li>
          <hr />
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
</html>
```

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl'
  });

  $routeProvider.when('/LetsTalk', {
    templateUrl: 'LetsTalk.html',
    controller: 'LetsTalkCtrl'
  });

  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirecTo: '/'});
}]);


app.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.message = '';
    console.log('welcome to home');
}]);

app.controller('LetsTalkCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'lets talk';
    console.log('lets talk');
}]);
```

I currently am not getting any error messages. What I do not understand is why I can not even get my console.log messages to appear, I assume that those messages are not appearing for the same reason that the actual content of my LetsTalk.html and home.html are not loading. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Typo: it should be `redirectTo`.

Comment: @georgeawg I tried that and still not seeing anything logged to the console :/

Comment: Try getting rid of the “#” in the anchor tag href

Comment: @tbone849 Tried this but still not getting anything to the console or content loading from the home.html page

Comment: Maybe you need to throw your code into codepen or something of that nature so we can better review what’s going on.

Comment: https://codepen.io/danerwilliams/pen/ydRXpa hopefully this will help, keep in mind that it is missing the actual html files that angular would route to, however. @tbone849

Answer (score 0):

** facepalm **

So it turns out I was missing the following line from my index.html page:

```
<div ng-view=""></div>
```